# How to run a gif file on Background Screen or Lock Screen?

Tags: windows-10

I am running Windows 10. How do I run an animated `gif` file on the background screen or lock screen?

My screen shows a static image instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use [wallpaper engine](http://store.steampowered.com/app/431960/Wallpaper_Engine/) as Desktopwallpaper, Lockscreen image i don't know